# passing in variable to python script run from command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

So I know the command to run a script from command prompt is:

```
python script.py var1 var2
```

and even using the package `subprocess`

```
import subprocess
subprocess(python script.py var1 var2)
```

But if var1 and/or var2 is a list, how could I achieve this. As it is right now, if we pass in `var1 as a list: ["test", "test"]`, then when we go to capture it using `sys.argv[element_number]`, the elements in the list appear to be broken up by the number of commas. In other words, i want to pass in the entire list so I can capture it as a variable in the script i am calling.

Comment: could you please clarify if you are calling this script as `python script.py "[ 1, 23, 4, 5]"` from command line.

Comment: @lazarus exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) module from the standard library. There are many related [questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=argparse+%5Bpython%5D) on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose when you are passing list as string in command line argument.
while capturing it through `sys.argv[index]` you are having issues because it has commas as it will be of string type.

you can parse the variable to required list.

```
import sys

def main(*argv, **kwargs):
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print 'Atleast one command line argument required'

    first_arg = sys.argv[1]
    # convert it to list
    first_arg_list = list(first_arg)
    # filter it according to requirement 
    first_arg_list_filtered = [ elem for elem in first_arg_list if elem not in '[],' ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: output: ['[', 't', 'e', 's', 't', ',', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', ']']

Comment: ''.join([ x for x in ['[', 't', 'e', 's', 't', ',', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', ']']  if x not in '[],' ]) will give "test test" if that's what you provided for command line argument